# Matlab GUI: how to add docked figure group?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, figure

I would like to be able to add a figure container to a matlab gui...

In core matlab, with a docked window style you can have a large number of plots stacked one behind the other, all within a figure container with a tabbed list along the side of the container that you can simply click to bring a particular figure to the front.

Is there a way to have this sort of figure container in a matlab gui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're open to play around with undocumented features, this can be done using the java objects behind the matlab figures, e.g. using a little [tool](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16650-setfigdockgroup) from the fileexchange.

This will create a new dock group, just like MATLAB's container for figures, editor etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use Ben Tordoff's [GUI Layout Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27758-gui-layout-toolbox). It contains functionality for tabbed panels and dockable/undockable panels that can contain figures, and many other capabilities that you'll find very useful if you are creating GUIs in MATLAB.

You will need to organize your GUI code slightly differently, but it's not hard to learn and there are great examples in the documentation.

It's not really possible to do what you're describing with just regular MATLAB: figures will just dock into the main MATLAB desktop, not into your GUI specifically. The best way (without GUI Layout Toolbox) would probably be to fake a row of tabs using buttons next to each other, with callbacks on the buttons that deleted/hid one plot and drew/revealed another. There is a function `uitab` that does tabs, but before R2014b it's undocumented, and it's a bit of a pain anyway. Better all round to use GUI Layout Toolbox.